# Comparing two graphs

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, graph

I need to compare many graphs(up to a few millions graph comparisons) and I wonder what is the fastest way to do that.

Graphs' vertices can have up to 8 neighbours/edges and vertex can have value 0 or 1. Rotated graph is still the same graph and every graph has identical number of vertices.

Graph can look like this:

[image: graph example]

Right now I'm comparing graphs by taking one vertex from first graph and comparing it with every vertex from second graph. If I find identical vertex then I check if both vertices' neighbours are identical and I repeat this until I know if graphs are identical or not.

This approach is too slow. Without discarding graphs that are for sure different, it takes more than 40 seconds to compare several thousands graphs with about one hundred vertices.

I was thinking about calculating unique value for every graph and then only compare values. I tried to do this, but I only managed to come up with values that if are equal then graphs may be equal and if values are different then graphs are different too.
If my program compares these values, then it calculates everything in about 2.5 second(which is still too slow).

And what is the best/fastest way to add vertex to this graph and update edges? Right now I'm storing this graph in `std::map< COORD, Vertex >` because I think searching for vertex is easier/faster that way.
COORD is vertex position on game board(vertices' positions are irrelevant in comparing graphs) and Vertex is:

```
struct Vertex
{
    Player player; // Player is enum, FIRST = 0, SECOND = 1
    Vertex* neighbours[8];
};
```

And this graph is representing current board state of Gomoku with wrapping at board edges and board size n*n where n can be up to 2^16.

I hope I didn't made too many errors while writing this. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: I can't prove it off the top of my head, but I think there may be a way to create a normalized representation of the graph. Then, you would need a transformation function that maps a graph to its normalized form. Prove that all equivalent graphs have the same normalized form, then you can reduce your problem to two transforms and a single compare.

Comment: To find out whether two graphs are similar or not, following factors can be checked
Number of vertices, number of edges, in degree and out degree, Euler cycle, Euler path.. etc

Comment: Your question is not really well defined.  When are two graphs 'the same'? Is it if they are isomorphic as unlabeled graphs?  Then you are trying to solve the graph ismorphism problem which is NP, but not known to be in P or NP-hard.  There is a library called 'nauty' that implements standard algorithms for it.

Comment: A different comment: Why would you store a Gomoku board as such a complicated structure instead of a 2d-array? The wrapping at board edges can be implemented using modulo arithmetic.

Comment: Hm. The generic graph isomorphism problem is apparently potentially NP-complete, but isn't yet known for sure to be so. This problem, of course, doesn't include your twist wherein the nodes themselves have values; I'm not sure if that makes it harder or easier, algorithmically speaking.

Comment: Are `neighbours[8]` guaranteed to be the adjacent board tiles?

Comment: @Tomas - Probably he saves boards corresponding to every move (though, i don't know what kind of game it is)

Comment: gomoku = tic-tac-toe-tuc-tee

Comment: Just a suggestion. If you are willing to use boost graph library instead, this might be interesting for you. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/graph/doc/isomorphism.html

Comment: @Thomas I'm not storing Gomoku board in 2d-array because board size can be up to 2^16 x 2^16 and I can have tens of thousands of game states or more. If I'm calculating correctly I would need about 4GB memory to store one game state. 2 game states are identical if you can get other game state through shifts or rotations. With board wrapping I can't just shift bottom left pawn to 0,0. At worst I would have to make 4n^2 shifts and rotations.

Comment: Are reflections of a board to be considered isomorphic to the original board?

Comment: @MichałIwanicki: Are you playing on an infinite board, or a finite board? 2^16 seems like a lot for gomoku.  I've played it on the classical 19x19 and the boundary never interferred with play.

Comment: no, only shifts and rotations.
@Thomas: board size is n x n. n is less or equal 2^16

Comment: You can define AND, OR, XOR, .. over Graph by considering Adjacency Matrix (Vertices Set)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to get each graph into a consistent representation, the natural way to do this is to create an ordered representation of the graph.

The first level of ordering is achieved by grouping according to the number of neighbours.

Each group of nodes with the same number of neighbours is then sorted by mapping their neighbours values (which are 0 and 1) on a binary number which is then used to enforce an order amongst the group nodes.

Then you can use a hashing function which iterates over each node of each group in the ordered form. The hashed value can then be used to provide an accelerated lookup

Comment: +1. And there is even C++ implementation available with description of algorithm - http://www.itk.ilstu.edu/faculty/portegys/research/graph/graph-hash.pdf

Answer (score 3):

The problem you're trying to solve is called [graph isomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem).

The problem is in NP (although it is not known whether it's NP-Complete) and no polynomial time algorithm for it has been found.

The algorithm you describe seems to take exponential time.

Comment: it is not known to be NP-complete, not 'not NP-complete'.

Comment: There are algorithms in P for special cases like planar graphs. His graph is special and almost planar, maybe there's a chance.

Comment: Graph isomorphism doesn't take into account that nodes may have values (here 0 and 1).

Comment: @abeln: Your edit is still not correct, it is not known if the problem is NP-complete, in P, or maybe neither (or both :) ).  The only thing that is known is that it is in NP: Given an isomorphism, one can quickly veryify that it is correct. So it could for instance still be that P!=NP but graph isomorphism is in P. It could also be that P!=NP and graph isomorphism is NP-complete.

Comment: @Thomas: I misread from Wikipedia: "It is known that the graph isomorphism problem is in the low hierarchy of class NP, which implies that it is not NP-complete unless the polynomial time hierarchy collapses to its second level"

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible suggestion for optimization.

I would recommend to try memoization (store all the vertex pairs that are found to be different), so that the next time those two vertices are compared you just do a simple lookup and reply. This may improve the performance (or worsen it), depending on the type of graphs you have.

Answer (score 0):

You have found out yourself that checking isomorphism can be done by checking one bord with all the n*n shifts times 8 rotations of the other, thus having `O(n^3)` complexity.

This can be reduced to `O(n^2)`. Let's shift only in one direction, say by moving the `x` axis.  Then we only have to find the proper `y`-offset.  For this, we concatenate the elements as follows for both graphs:

```
. . 1 .            0 . . 3
0 1 . .     =>     0 1 2 .     =>     0 3 0 1 2 0 2
. 0 . .            0 . 2 .
_______            
1 2 3 4            ^---- a 0 indicates start of a row
```

We get two arrays of size `n` and we have to check whether one is a cyclic permutation of the other. For this, we concatenate array a with itself and search for the other.

For example if the two arrays would be `a=0301202` and `b=0203012` we search for `0203012` in `03012020301202` using KMP or similar, which runs in `O(n + 2n)=O(n)` time (we can get rid of the whole preprocessing since the first array always is the same).

Combining this `O(n)` x-check with the `n` y-shifts and the `8` rotations gives `O(n^2)` overall complexity by using `O(n)` additional space.

Comment: Only 4 rotations. And isn't `O(n^2)` complexity too big? Especially if n can be as big as 2^16 and I would have to check thousands of boards. And number of pieces on board could be very small compared to map size, that's why I tried to think of some algorithm which complexity would depend only on number of pieces.

Comment: I don't think a deterministic algorithm can be faster than `O(n^2)`.

Comment: But can't comparing complexity be independent from board size?  

And can you give better example to your method? How to compare for example:
`. 1 .`  `0 . .` `. 1 .`     and    `1 . .`
      `. . 0`
         `1 . .`

Comment: To the board size: If `0 0 0 0 0 ... 0` (`z` times `0`) gets replaced by `-z`, this algorithm is independend of the board size. I meant `n` to be the number of nodes.

Comment: To the example: First all cyclic permutations in `x`-direction are generated, then the offset in `y`-direction get calculated. In your example the `y`-offset is equal to `0`.