# Complexity to check two graphs are isomorphic?

Tags: algorithm, graph, time-complexity, isomorphism

Compute the complexity - 
(i) Given two graphs and check whether graphs are isomorphic or not?
(ii) Subgraph matching.

Answer (score 0):

ad (i) - This is an open problem, see ["Recognition of graph isomorphism"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism#Recognition_of_graph_isomorphism) or ["Graph isomorphism problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem).

ad (ii) - See ["Matching (graph theory)"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#Algorithms_and_computational_complexity).

Comment: The complexity is O(n^3).

Comment: Could you elaborate on what's the problem? Did you provide all the constraints?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819319/comparing-two-graphs/15820757#15820757

Comment: I can't load the picture in the question but they are definitely discussing some special case, not the general problem. So for general case I refer back to my original answer, some special cases (such as when a graph is actually only a cycle) can have polynomial complexity.